# How to create 2 SQLite tables in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm pretty new to android and using java in general. I've been trying to create a SQLite database and have followed a few tutorials, however I'm still unsure as to how I create 2 tables within the database. I was able to get one table working but not the second one. I'll attach the relevant code, thanks!

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FitnessApp.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "saved_workout_weights";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_3 = "EXERCISE";
    public static final String COL_4 = "WEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_5 = "REPS";

    public static final String TABLE2_NAME = "saved_workout_cardio";
    public static final String COL_1a = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2a = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_3a = "TIME";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,DATE TEXT,EXERCISE TEXT,WEIGHT INTEGER,REPS INTEGER)"
                + TABLE2_NAME + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,DATE TEXT,TIME INTEGER");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+TABLE2_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one `CREATE TABLE` statement per table.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ...;
CREATE TABLE table2 ...;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've done 2 separate create statements now as shown below, however still no luck. Is this how you meant for me to do it? thanks!


`@Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,DATE TEXT,EXERCISE TEXT,WEIGHT INTEGER,REPS INTEGER)"); db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE2_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,DATE TEXT,TIME INTEGER)"); }`

Answer (score 0):

The create queries should be run separately: two SQL statements in two `db.execSQL()` calls.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've done 2 separate create queries now as shown below, however still no luck. Is this how you meant for me to do it? thanks!

Comment: `@Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,DATE TEXT,EXERCISE TEXT,WEIGHT INTEGER,REPS INTEGER)"); db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE2_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,DATE TEXT,TIME INTEGER)"); }`